# Lubuntu ignores sleep mode prefrence

Tags: lubuntu

I may be posting in the wrong forums, since this is a Lubuntu question. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this and I'm desperate for an answer. Anyway, I have a Dell Inspiron N4010 laptop running Lubuntu 13.10 (latest version). I needed to disable automatic sleep/hibernate, so I went into the Power Settings and disabled everything that had to do with that. It still goes into sleep mode after 5-10 minutes. I need to be able to disable it because I frequently download files and run SH scripts and go grab a coffee (or two).

Help?! My specs are:

CPU: Intel Core i3 370M Dual Core (with Hyper threading) @2.40GHz on the first core and the second one is running @2.39GHz

RAM: 8GB Crucial DDR3/1066

HDD: Oh, some segate something :) I don't think it matters much

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics

Comment: It is still Ubuntu though - this question is inverse to usual as you provide your computer's stats straight away, and think this is the wrong forum, even though other people post stuff about Linux Mint etc without a care. +1 for that, and an answer in a second.

Comment: Wow, even a 0.01 difference it GHz processor values - you could just put 'Intel Core i3 370M Dual Core @2.40 GHz Hyper-threaded'. +1

Answer (score 2):

You may just need to modify the systemd configuration - so run this:

```
nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

And then modify the contents according to [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html) or [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man5/logind.conf.5.html).

Look for [`Idle Action`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#IdleAction=), and set it to `ignore`.
You can also configure [`IdleActionSec`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html#IdleActionSec=), which should set the time until it carries out `IdleAction`.

You may also want to configure a few other things, like `HandleLidSwitch` to stop it suspending when closing the laptop lid etc *(I set it to `lock` -  and is why I know this stuff)*.

*This is partially from memory, but hopefully in the right direction. Any corrections welcome*